# How to loop through set_fact attributes in another task of ansible playbook

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-facts

I am struggling with the looping using with_items from the set_fact results in my ansible playbook.

```
- set_fact:
    TAGNAME: "TEST-EC2-0{{item}}"
    TAGOWNER: LOGIN
    TAGROLE: DB
  with_sequence: start=01 end="{{ count }}"
  register: tagname
```

Below is the result of set_fact using debug I got this.

```
"results": [
    {
        "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
        "_ansible_item_label": "1", 
        "_ansible_item_result": true, 
        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
        "ansible_facts": {
            "TAGNAME": "TEST-EC2-01", 
            "TAGOWNER": "LOGIN", 
            "TAGROLE": "DB"
        }, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "item": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
        "_ansible_item_label": "2", 
        "_ansible_item_result": true, 
        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
        "ansible_facts": {
            "TAGNAME": "TEST-EC2-02", 
            "TAGOWNER": "LOGIN", 
            "TAGROLE": "DB"
        }, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "item": "2"
    }
]
```

With this given output, I want to use all the "TAGNAME" in the below ec2 task for tagging purpose whenever I create multiple instances using COUNT module.

```
    ec2:
    ....
    ....
    ....
    instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ item.TAGNAME }}"
        Owner: "LOGIN"
    with_items: "{{ tagname.results }}"
```

But when I trigger the playbook I am getting below error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'local/apps/roles/EC2_Deploy/tasks/ec2_creation.yml': line 217, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create Instances\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I am not sure what and where I am missing. Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: `item.ansible_facts.TAGNAME` more probably, based on your JSON structure.

Comment: I am getting this error ```fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'local/apps/roles/EC2_Deploy/tasks/ec2_creation.yml': line 217, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create Instances\n  ^ here\n"}```